# OpenSSL: what is the difference between organizationName and unstructuredName?

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to use OpenSSL to generate a certificate signing request. I noticed that when going through the prompts, OpenSSL by default asks for "organizationName", and then later asks for "unstructuredName". The prompts for both indicate that the 'company name' should go in them.

The question is: why are we being asked twice? What is the difference between these 2 entries?

In my setup, I will be issuing CSRs on behalf of other companies - ie., these companies are asking me to get and instal the certificates for them. I am suspecting, therefore, that perhaps I should be putting my own company name in one of these fields, and the client's company in the other.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: There is no code to try here. When you run the _openssl_ command from the command line, it asks for these 2 pieces of information. Are they different pieces of information, or the same? What are they used for in the CSR or in the trusted certificate? In the _openssl.conf_ configuration file, there is no explanation. The online docs for OpenSSL do not clarify what they are, either. Yet, they are both there by default...

Comment: If you have openssl installed in your system, have a look at the _openssl.conf_ file that is installed by default. There, you will see the default values and user prompts for these 2 fields: `organizationName = Organization Name (eg, company)` and `unstructuredName = An optional company name`...??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may find this [document](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-9-v2/pkcs-9.pdf) useful.

In Section 5.2.2:

> The interpretation of unstructured names is intended to be specified by certificate issuers
>   etc.; no particular interpretation is required.

This field is part of the certificate request; The certificate issuer may look up this name or not. But this field will not appear in the resulting certificate, unlike organizationName.

Comment: Sounds like it's for internal use by the certificate authority, then - and in that case, its usage probably varies from authority to authority... I guess it's probably best to leave it matching the organizationName.

Comment: @LuxLogica when requesting certificates I generally leave unstructuredName/"optional company name" blank (the default, with openssl). Haven't had a problem with the 50+ certs I've ordered across at least 5 CAs :)